# Showing shorter list from long domain list?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, domains

I have a geodatabase with a feature class that has several domains attached to various attributes in the table. A couple of the attribute have very long domains associated with them, where much of the data is not used any more. For example: one of the fields is for the data observer; we currently only need four of the people listed and not the entire list of all the data collectors for the past 12 years (which is like 30 people). It would be much more convenient to just be able to have a shorter drop down list for the field data collectors.

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1:**

Open the GeoDataBase properties, select the Domain Tab.

Find the Domain Name in question
- remove the names you no longer want to include in the list

**Option #2:**

go into the GDB properties, select the Domain Tab.

- Create a new Domain
- add the values you desire
- assign the newly created domain to the appropriate attribute field within the desired feature class

Comment: If I do either of those would the previous data that does have the unwanted names then throw an error, since there will be names in the field that are not included in the domain?

Comment: no, but if you try to change existing values it will only let you use the new ones in the revised/new domain list. dont edit the existing values and be sure to double check before saving edits

Comment: you can also enable the option to "Allow Null Values"